# service response empty

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki doesn't make it clear if response or request of a ROS service can be empty, and what will happen when either is empty.

I have seen `rospy.Service` fails if the handler returns None, so I guess ROS services without any response are not supported. Otherwise, what should the handler return?

But I am still not clear if ROS services with empty requests are officially supported. I see services with empty request can be called with no problem, but it would be nice to see this documented, so that when we see some tools cannot work with this case, we know it is a bug and will try fix it.

Best regards,
Yong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302619/service-response-empty/) by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have seen `rospy.Service` fails if the handler returns None, so I guess ROS services without any response are not supported.

`None` != empty response. `None` indicates an error on the server side.

See the documentation ([wiki/rospy/Overview/Services - Providing services](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Providing_services), emphasis mine):

> Create a new ROS Service with the specified name, service type (the auto-generated service class), and handler. The handler will be invoked with the service request message and should return the appropriate service response message. **If the handler returns None or raises an exception, an error will be passed to the client.**

Furthermore:

> Otherwise, what should the handler return?

Every service definition always consists of a *request* and a *response* part (top and bottom of the `.srv` definition respectively). Services that have "nothing" on the response side still have a `Response` class generated, but it will just not contain any fields.

Service handlers that should return an empty response should therefore still instantiate a `Response` object and return that.

See again [wiki/rospy/Overview/Services - Providing services](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Providing_services) on the wiki.

> I see services with empty request can be called with no problem, but it would be nice to see this documented

I think the `rospy` overview page on services documents this quite well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-06**:
Thanks. So the handler can return `args`, `kwargs` (a `dict`) or a `Reponse` object directly.

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-06**:
Just doing some testing. The service call doesn't work for me though.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:
If you're having issues with some specific piece of code I would suggest to post a new question. This particular question was about whether service server behaviour with empty responses was documented and specced. It is.

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-06**:
OK. got it work. will do.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The request and response parts of a service request are both allowed to be empty. For example, std_srvs/Empty is an officially supported type: http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_srvs/html/srv/Empty.html

As a note, the handler for `rospy.Service` must always return the service's result type, even if it is empty. The [rospy.Service docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_service.Service-class.html) explicitly state that returning `None` from the service handler is considered a failure of the service call:

> **handler** (fn(req)->resp) - callback function for processing service request. Function takes in a ServiceRequest and returns a ServiceResponse of the appropriate type. Function may also return a list, tuple, or dictionary with arguments to initialize a ServiceResponse instance of the correct type.
> If handler cannot process request, it may either return None, to indicate failure, or it may raise a rospy.ServiceException to send a specific error message to the client. Returning None is always considered a failure.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-06**:
Thanks. Sorry it seems I cannot choose both answers.